# bs.as and unicode strings

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

Does bs.as work with unicode strings?

```
[@bs.deriving jsConverter]

type filterable = [
  | `Material
  | [@bs.as {js|üüüüü|js}] `Umlaut
];
```

is giving me

> Unused BuckleScript attribute: bs.as   Some fatal warnings were
>   triggered (1 occurrences)

Comment: Certainly doesn't seem like it! It's a common problem with BuckleScript that features you might expect to interact well together just fail horribly. You should make an issue on [the github repo](https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript)

Comment: @glennsl when things work though, it's pretty glorious. https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/issues/3142